# Apache Camel HTTP Component

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot, camel

Добрый день возникла проблема следующего характера. Пишу микросервис который на вход принимает json, из этого json делает запрос к стороннему ресурсу, и уже получившиеся данные возвращает пользователю. Проблема следующего характера. Когда добавляю правила

```
 CamelContext  camel = new DefaultCamelContext();

  camel.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
                  from("direct:httpRoute")
                    .log("Http Route started")
                    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD).constant(GET)
                    .to("https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getcurrencies")
                    .log("Response : ${body}");
        }
    });

    camel.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    camel.stop();
```

Получаю следующую ошибку.
"org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getcurrencies, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar." В данном примере,я показал,что хочу обратиться к https://api.bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getcurrencies и результат вывести в log. Почему не работает? Помогите пожалуйста уже 2 день бьюсь с этим верблюдом и не как не даётся)

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, отсутствует зависимость в classpath.
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html

Если используете maven, то в pom.xml дожно быть такое:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.x</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```